# Autolayout with specific constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I have problem or maybe wrong understanding of constraints in general with view controller form photo below.

I already implemented scroll view and it is working properly. Photo below showing Content View with two subviews (with the same name: View). What I would like to achieve is to set first View (the blue one) to be exactly on edges of the screen and second one (green view) to be visible only when user scroll down on this page. Is it possible to achieve these just using autolayuots or I need to do some hard code work. What is the best approaches for solving this taking in account that I need this app to work with all king of iPhones.

At the bottom of the green view is located tab bar but it is not visible on this photo.

[image: Current situation]

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight-forward...

1. Pin your scroll view to Zero on all four sides.
2. set Blue Top, Leading and Trailing all to Zero to superview (the scroll view)
3. set Blue width equal to scroll view width
4. set Blue height equal to scroll view height
5. set Green width and height each equal to Blue width and height
6. set Green "center horizontally" to Blue
7. set Green Top to Zero from Blue bottom (vertical spacing)
8. set Green Bottom to Zero to superview (the scroll view)

That should do it :)

**Edit:** whoops, corrected step 4 (Blue height should be *equal* to scroll view height, *not* multiplied by 0.5)